# Parallel BMSs with LiFePO4 Packs

Tags: batteries, lithium, lifepo4, bms

I'm trying to design a BMS that allows for multiple larger packs to be connected together in parallel (say, multiple 4S LiFePO4 packs). Using an unconnected conventional BMS SOC there's obviously the risk of unregulated balance current between various voltage cells which could damage cells or the BMS.

I'm wondering if say, current is limited into the pack (at 0.3C for example) and a data connection is made between packs, and packs are top balanced like the cells are if this mitigates those risks?

[image: Distributed BMS]

Comment: I'm afraid that that's a bit unclear. A diagram or more detailed explanation is almost certainly going to be needed. (I understand all the words but not the specifics of the problem).

Comment: Thanks @RussellMcMahon

Comment: If you have BMSs on each pack and LiFePo4s, there should be no problem o long term whatsoever. LiFePo4s are designed for more cycles than Li-Ion and don't have the safety issues Li-Ion does. Do you try to accomplish something special with the additional balancing ?